# a function acting like java's nextInt() in C++?

Tags: c++

is there any mechanism alternative to X.nextInt() and X.nextCahr() etc in C++?
which lets getting integers seperated by white space characters(space, tab and newline) from input.

Comment: Like `int n; std::cin >> n;`?

Comment: The input operator separates on *all* whitespace.

Comment: You can even use other characters as delimiters if you wish: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376199/how-can-i-use-non-default-delimiters-when-reading-a-text-file-with-stdfstream

Comment: You can split lines first with `getline` and then apply the above logic on stringstreams formed from each line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int k, l, m, n; 

cin >> k >> l >> m >> n;
```