# How do I ignore a character with stringstream in C++

Tags: c++, wavefront

So I'm writing a Wavefront OBJ loader. I was able to get the vertex, normals, and texture coordinates, but I'm having problems with the faces. I'm trying to figure how to ignore certain characters, like "//" and "/" in C++ using std::stringstream. Is there anyway to do this? Thanks.

Here's my load function:

```
bool Model::load(std::string file_name) {
   std::string line; 
   std::ifstream file(file_name.c_str());
   if(file.is_open()) 
   {
      while(std::getline(file, line))
      {  
        std::stringstream stream(line);
        stream >> line;

        if(line == "#") 
        {
            // ignore.
        }
        if(line == "v") // vertices
        { 
            double x, y, z;
            stream >> x >> y >> z;
            v.push_back(x);
            v.push_back(y);
            v.push_back(z);
            #ifdef DEBUG
            std::cout << "v " << x << " "<< y << " " << z << "\n";
            #endif
        }
        if(line == "vt") // texture coordinates
        {
            double u, v;
            stream >> u >> v;
            vt.push_back(u);
            vt.push_back(v);
            #ifdef DEBUG
            std::cout << "vt " << u << " "<< v << "\n";
            #endif
        }
        if(line == "vn") // normals
        {
            double x, y, z;
            stream >> x >> y >> z;
            vn.push_back(x);
            vn.push_back(y);
            vn.push_back(z);
            #ifdef DEBUG
            std::cout << "vn " << x << " "<< y << " " << z << "\n";
            #endif
        }
        if(line == "f")
        {
           short a, b, c;
           stream >> a; stream >> b; stream >> c;
           a--; b--; c--;

           f.push_back(a);
           f.push_back(b);
           f.push_back(c);

           std::cout << a << " " << b << " " << c << "\n";              
        }

    }
    file.close();
    return true;    
  } return false;
}
```

Comment: Get Boost::Spirit and implement the full blown parser maybe?

Answer (score 2):

You could try checking for the characters you don't want directly.  In the `if` statement you could put `continue` or `break` or nothing depending on what you want to do.

```
if (line == "/" || line == "//") {

    continue; //if you want to move on to the next loop iteration

    break;    //if you want to leave the loop

    //Do nothing if you want to continue in the current loop iteration
}
```

Comment: For the second example, `break` will take you out of the while loop and straight to `file.close()` is this intended?

Answer (score 0):

With your approach you may use a specific locale to determine the delimiters for the `>>` operator - which is pretty nasty as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10376445/3426025).

In my parser I try to read the first tripplet ("V" or "V/VT" or "V//VN" or "V/VT/VN") parsing character by character, then split the rest of the string expecting the same number of `/` per vertex - which I found to be quite robust.