# Show words from a file with a minimum given number of vowels

Tags: c++, algorithm, counting

I'm trying to solve a problem and i can't figure out how to do it.
The problem says that given an input file which has on the first line a number k and on the next lines some words, K is the minimum number of vowels that a word needs to have to be printed in the console.

```
Example:
Input: test.in
cars
are...great and awesome

Output:
If k is 2 the result should be:
are
great
awesome
And also it should not take into account spaces or other characters like .,!,? and so on.
```

What i have so far:

```
 int main(){

    ifstream fin("dataTest.in");
    char s[250];
    int k;
    fin>>k;
    int nrVowels=0;

    while(fin>>s) {

         int n = strlen(s);

            for(int i=0; i < n; i++)

            {
                    if (s[i] == 'a' ||  s[i] == 'e' ||  s[i] == 'o' ||  s[i] == 'i' || s[i] == 'u'){
                        nrVowels++;
                        if(nrVowels == k){
                            cout<<"Here i guess i should print the word?";
                        }
                    }
            }
    }

}
```

As you can see from the code my problem is that i'm not really sure how i should print the word and how would i know where the word is ending because i don't want to print only a part of the word.
Do you guys have any ideas on how i should do this?

Comment: You are not resetting your vowel variable counter `nrVowels` which means that it will only print once. Put the `nrVowels = 0` before the for loop

Comment: I did that now and it prints a word multiple times:( I'm printing a word using cout<<s; is that correct?

Answer (score 3):

```
std::ifstream file("Read.txt");
int number;
file>>number;
std::string str; 
auto vowels = [](char c){return c == 'a' ||  c == 'e' ||  c  == 'o' ||  c  == 'i' || c  == 'u';};
while (std::getline(file, str))
{
    if(std::count_if(str.cbegin(), str.cend(), vowels) >= number){
        std::cout<<str<<'\n';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First fix obvious problems

```
 int main(){
   ifstream fin("dataTest.in");
   char s[250];
   int k;
   fin>>k;

  while(fin>>s) {
    int nrVowels=0; // moved
    int n = strlen(s);

    for(int i=0; i < n; i++) {
      if (s[i] == 'a' ||  s[i] == 'e' ||  s[i] == 'o' ||  s[i] == 'i' || s[i] == 'u') {
        nrVowels++;

        if(nrVowels == k) {
          cout<< s;;
          break; // inner for
        }
      }
    }
  }    
}
```

You have

```
char s[250];
```

in combination with

```
fin>>s
```

is a potential buffer overrun. changing s to

```
std::string s;
```

now you get

```
    int n = strlen(s);
```

for free.

```
if (s[i] == 'a' ||  s[i] == 'e' ||  s[i] == 'o' ||  s[i] == 'i' || s[i] == 'u')
```

is rather long it would be better to say

```
if (IsVowel(s[i]) {
```

by making (as Kaldrr proposed)

```
auto IsVowel = [](const char c){return c == 'a' ||  c == 'e' ||  c  == 'o' ||  c  == 'i' || c  == 'u';};
```

This gives

```
int main(){
  ifstream fin("dataTest.in");
  std::string s;
  int k;
  fin>>k;

  auto IsVowel = [](const char c){return c == 'a' ||  c == 'e' ||  c  == 'o' ||  c  == 'i' || c  == 'u';};

  while(fin>>s) {
    int nrVowels=0; // moved

    for(int i=0; i < n; i++) {
      if (IsVowel(s[i]) {
        nrVowels++;

        if(nrVowels == k) {
          cout<< s;;
          break; // inner for
        }
      }
    }
  }    
}
```

But there is still the problem of each word is tested instead of each string.

```
int main(){
  ifstream fin("dataTest.in");
  std::string s;
  int k;
  fin>>k;

  auto IsVowel = [](const char c) { return c == 'a' ||  c == 'e' ||  c  == 'o' ||  c  == 'i' || c  == 'u'; };
  auto IsSplit = [](const char c) { return isspace(s[i]) || ispunct(s[i]); };

  while(fin>>s) {
    int nrVowels=0; // moved

    for(int i=0; i < s.length; i++) {
      if (IsVowel(s[i]) {
        nrVowels++;

        if(nrVowels == k) {
          cout << s; // wrong writes all the string and not the word
          break; // inner for
        }
      } else {
        if (IsSplit(s[i]) {
          nrVowels = 0; // restart at each word.
        }
      }
    }
  }    
}
```

What we want is

```
while(fin>>s) {
  auto split = Split(s);

  for (const auto& str : split) {
    if (HasEnougVowels(str, k)) {
      cout << s;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your requirements state that *"K is the minimum number of vowels that a word needs to have to be printed in the console"*, which would translate to the *greater or equal* condition

```
if (nrVowels >= k) { /* print word */ }
```

However, your code prints the word as soon as `k` vowels are found, so you can keep your condition as is. But you should break the inner loop once the required count was reached.

Also, as it was commented already, you need to reset the `nrVowels` counter for each word that you inspect. Better yet: make `nrVowels` a local scope variable within the body of your while-loop.

Some hints regarding your code that are not strictly necessary to solve the problem:

- use `std::string` instead of char arrays.
- use a single variable that contains all your vowels
- don't count vowels, just ensure there are at least two in the word

code:

```
ifstream fin("dataTest.in");
std::string s;
const char* vowels = "aeiou";
int k;
fin>>k;

while(fin>>s)
{
    // If the string contains at least two vowels, the find results will differ
    if (s.find_first_of(vowels) != s.find_last_of(vowels))
    {
        std::cout << s << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for answering!
I've modified my code with this based on your help:

```
int main(){

    ifstream fin("dateTest.in");
    char s[250];
    int k;
    fin>>k;
    int nrVowels=0;

    while(fin>>s) {

         int n = strlen(s);
            nrVowels=0;
            for(int i=0; i < n; i++)

            {
                    if (s[i] == 'a' ||  s[i] == 'e' ||  s[i] == 'o' ||  s[i] == 'i' || s[i] == 'u'){
                        nrVowels++;

                        if(nrVowels >= k){
                            cout<<s<<" ";
                            break;
                        }

                    }

            }
    }

}
```

It kind of works now but i need also to separate words that have.,? and so on. How should that be done?

Comment: Answers are not used like a discussion thread but only as actual answers to the initial question. Regarding additional separators, you might be interested in the following: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10376445/5265292