# Stream extraction without white space - how to store list from text file into an array

Tags: c++, arrays

Say I have a list like this in a file (names.txt) where instead of just, name1 name2 name3 name4 etc. it has quotations separating the strings.

"MARY","PATRICIA","LINDA","BARBARA","ELIZABETH","JENNIFER","MARIA","SUSAN","MARGARET","DOROTHY","LISA",
"NANCY","KAREN","BETTY"

I was using something along these lines, but this just stores the whole thing as one string into array[0] because the stream extraction only recognizes white space...

```
ifstream file("names.txt");
    if(file.is_open())
    {
        string array[50];

        for(int i = 0; i < 50; ++i)
        {
            file >> array[i];
        }
        cout << array[0];
    }
```

How am I to separate each name as a separate string here in its current format?

Comment: Add the tag of the programming language you are looking for

Comment: boost string split is a good start https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/string_algo/usage.html#id2728530

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost/algorithm/split_id1155181.html

Comment: Just change the delimiter from just whitespace to include quotes and comma (and not include spaces).  Here https://repl.it/repls/RadiantGregariousCleantech is an example almost completely copied verbatim from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/ctype_char   Of course it won't work if the names include quotes or commas.  In which case maybe use a library like https://github.com/suspend0/csvpp or maybe just parse it yourself (Spirit would work or any parsing library)

Comment: Here is another answer that is almost exactly what you are after: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10376445/2193968

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file character by character. Then

- first wait for an opening "
- If it arrives, change mode and
- copy the character to a temporary name string
- If we detect a closing ", we copy the name to our names vector and start from beginning

Info. Since we do not know the number of names, we use a dynamic growing "array", a so called `std::vector`

Please see one of many possible example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {

    // Open a file and check, if it is open
    if (std::ifstream fileStream("names.txt"); fileStream) {

        // Here we will store all names
        std::vector<std::string> names{};

        // This is for one name, we will build it character by character
        std::string name{};

        // We will read the file character wise
        char c{};

        // We build a little state machine. Either we wait for a starting " or we copy data
        bool copyCharacter{ false };

        // Read all characters from file. We could have also used while (fileStream.get(c))
        while (fileStream >> std::noskipws >> c) {

            // Are we waiting for the opening " or not
            if (!copyCharacter) {

                // We are waiting for the opening ". Check if we have read one.
                if (c == '\"') {

                    // We read an opening ". In the next step, we will copy the characters into the name
                    copyCharacter = true;
                }
            }
            else {
                // We are in copy mode. This will end with a closing ". Check, if we read one complete name
                if (c == '\"') {

                    // We found a closing " after a name. Therefore we stop this mode and wait for an opening " again
                    copyCharacter = false;
                    // We found a complete name. Add it to our target names
                    names.push_back(std::move(name));
                    // Temporary name will be reset, to be ready to read next name
                    name = {};
                }
                else {
                    // Copy mode. Add character to name
                    name += c;
                }
            }
        }
        // Show debug output
        std::cout << "\nWe have read " << names.size() << " names. Those are:\n\n";
        for (const std::string name : names) std::cout << name << '\n';
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "\n\n***Error: Could not open source file\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

There is a 2nd possibility. You can use the comma as delimiter. There is a function [std::getline](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)

So, first read the string name by name, then remove the " and then add the name list to our vector of names:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {

    // Open a file and check, if it is open
    if (std::ifstream fileStream("names.txt"); fileStream) {

        // Here we will store all names
        std::vector<std::string> names{};

        // This is for one name, including quotes
        std::string name{};

        // Read a complete name, until the next comma, include quotes
        while (std::getline(fileStream, name, ',')) {

            // Get the substring of name, without the quotes
            names.emplace_back(name.substr(1, name.size() - 2));
        }
        // Show debug output
        std::cout << "\nWe have read " << names.size() << " names. Those are:\n\n";
        for (const std::string name : names) std::cout << name << '\n';
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "\n\n***Error: Could not open source file\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And the most advanced and complex solution is to use `std::regex`

But this is maybe too much for now.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <regex>
#include <algorithm>

std::regex re{R"((\w+))"};
int main() {

    // Open a file and check, if it is open
    if (std::ifstream fileStream("names.txt"); fileStream) {

        // Here we will store all names
        std::vector<std::string> names{};

        // Read a complete line with all names in it
        for (std::string line{}; std::getline(fileStream, line);) {

            // Split the line in single names and copy the name to our names vector
            std::copy(std::sregex_token_iterator(line.begin(), line.end(), re), {}, std::back_inserter(names));
        }
        // Show debug output
        std::cout << "\nWe have read " << names.size() << " names. Those are:\n\n";
        for (const std::string name : names) std::cout << name << '\n';
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "\n\n***Error: Could not open source file\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```